# How do I write a pointcut that doesn't catch subclasses?

Tags: java, aspectj

Currently I have a pointcut that catches a parent class's call of a method.

What I have is:

```
@After("call (public void ParentInterface.method(..)) && target(instance)")
public void intercept(A instance) {
}
```

Where my inheritance structure is **B** *is a* **A** *is a* **ParentInterface**.
I don't want the pointcut to intercept any instance of B's call to method(). Is this possible?

**Edit:**
I don't want it to be:

```
@After("call (public void A.method(..)) && target(instance)")
```

Because then when there's a for loop as such:

```
for(ParentInterface obj:list) {
   obj.method();
}
```

The call wouldn't be intercepted because there isn't a pointcut that intercepts it.

Comment: You can probably use an "if" statement in the pointcut - something like: call (public void A.method(..)) && target(instance) && if (! instance instanceof B)). See - https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-pcadvice.html

Comment: @Lin Totally didn't notice that I could have if statements in pointcuts, will test more. Only thing is I don't think I would do !instanceof because then I would have to include one for each subclass, I'll probably try something along the lines of if(instance.getClass() == A.class). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, unfortunately you cannot do it directly with a pointcut, but you can use reflection in your advice instead:

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface ParentInterface {
    void myMethod();
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class A implements ParentInterface {
    @Override
    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println("  myMethod -> " + this + "\n");
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class B extends A {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("  doSomething -> " + this);
        myMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().myMethod();
        new B().doSomething();

        ParentInterface[] objects = { new A(), new B(), new A(), new B() };
        for (ParentInterface object : objects)
            object.myMethod();
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.After;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;

import de.scrum_master.app.A;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @After("call(public void de.scrum_master.app.ParentInterface.myMethod(..)) && target(instance)")
    public void intercept(A instance, JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        if (instance.getClass() != A.class)
            return;
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

Now please note how the log output only shows aspect output on instaces of exactly `A`, but not on subclasses like `B`:

```
call(void de.scrum_master.app.A.myMethod())
  myMethod -> de.scrum_master.app.A@4a574795

  doSomething -> de.scrum_master.app.B@f6f4d33
  myMethod -> de.scrum_master.app.B@f6f4d33

call(void de.scrum_master.app.ParentInterface.myMethod())
  myMethod -> de.scrum_master.app.A@23fc625e

  myMethod -> de.scrum_master.app.B@3f99bd52

call(void de.scrum_master.app.ParentInterface.myMethod())
  myMethod -> de.scrum_master.app.A@4f023edb

  myMethod -> de.scrum_master.app.B@3a71f4dd
```

Comment: Why not use an if statement within the pointcut? Something like: call (public void A.method(..)) && target(instance) && if (! instance instanceof B))...?

Comment: Because `A` could have subclasses other than `B` and the solution is not generic. Sure, you can put the condition into an `if()` condition within the pointcut, but still then it should be: `... && if (instance.getClass() != A.class)`

Comment: Furthermore, in annotation-style syntax you need an extra method which needs to be static, what you suggest only works in native AspectJ syntax. This is why I did not suggest it in the first place. Annotation style has limited means of using `if()` conditions within pointcuts, my solution is the only one that works in @AspectJ style.